# How to search for items in a list in a dataframe and count them

Tags: python, list, dataframe, count

I have the following dataframe with its output.

```
import pandas as pd
animal = ["monkey"]  + ["tiger"] + ["bat"]
valores = [1] + [2] + [3]
dframe = pd.DataFrame({"animal": animal, "valor": valores})
```

dataframe:

```
    animal  valor
0   monkey  1
1   tiger   2
2   bat     3
```

I have a list that I want to search for item by item in the dataframe and if match then creates a new column with a counter, the word can be uppercase or lowercase and would sum equally.

```
other_list = ['monkey', 'tiger', 'Tiger','tiger','Monkey']

    animal  valor count
0   monkey  1     2
1   tiger   2     3
2   bat     3     0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part, I'd go with @Dani, but convert counter to series:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = pd.Series(Counter(map(str.lower, other_list)), name='counts')
```

The second part to add this to the dataframe, I'd use `append` or `join` to avoid looping:

```
dframe = dframe.set_index('animal').join(counts).reset_index()
dframe['counts'] = dframe.counts.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
other_list = ['monkey', 'tiger', 'Tiger','tiger','Monkey']
counts = Counter(map(str.lower, other_list))

dframe['count'] = [counts.get(ani.lower(), 0) for ani in dframe['animal']]

print(dframe)
```

**Output**

```
   animal  valor  count
0  monkey      1      2
1   tiger      2      3
2     bat      3      0
```